# What is the accurate syntax for SQLite JDBC Connections?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

This is may look like a repeated question but, it is not. I have tried looking for an answer for this over 48 hours with no result.

Firstly, is closing `PreparedStatment` & `ResultSet` necessary in SQLite JDBC Connection? because I am unable to do so.

```
try {
        Class.forName(database.getJDBC_DRIVER());
        cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(database.getDB_URL());
        p = cnn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = p.executeQuery();
        p.close();
        cnn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            System.out.println(p.isClosed());
            if (cnn != null) cnn.close();
            System.out.println(p.isClosed());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I closed `PreparedStatement` inside the try block. However, When I'm checking the state of same outside the try block, the result is always false. (which means it isn't closed).

Besides, if I have below code in the finally block, it throws an error stating the connection is closed. I am super confused on what to do. Should I just leave it as it is. Wouldn't my code have some leakage?

```
} finally {
    try {
        if (p != null) p.close(); *// It errors out here...*
        if (cnn != null) cnn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the stack trace -

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.internalClose(CoreStatement.java:109)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.close(JDBC3Statement.java:35)
    at tg.cat.DropDown.getData(DropDown.java:28)
    at tg.loginscreen.LoginScreenLayout.<init>(LoginScreenLayout.java:22)
    at tg.cat.CatMain.getScene(CatMain.java:27)
    at tg.cat.CatMain.start(CatMain.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/855499929.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1635925971.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What does `finally` do?

Comment: in finally block, I attempt to close the connection again. Just in case, connection doesn't at first attempt due to any error. At the same time, I do same with PreparedStatment however, it errors out saying - Connection is closed.

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about SQLite as much as a question about the Java SE JDBC API.  It would be helpful to provide a stack trace of the error you are getting.  Also, the JDBC tutorial on the Oracle Java language website will cover all the material you wish to know: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: Hi Scott, I have commented where it throws the error and have also added stack trace to my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `finally` block is executed regardless of whether an exception was thrown or not. So you don't need to use it to close the connection **again**, but to use it as the only place you close the connection. Second, note that closing a connection will not reset the variable to `null`:

```
try {
    Class.forName(database.getJDBC_DRIVER());
    cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(database.getDB_URL());
    p = cnn.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = p.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (rs != null) { 
            rs.close();
        }
        if (p != null) { 
            p.close();
        }
        if (cnn != null) { 
            cnn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't close an object, not much I can do");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mureinik is right, but even better to use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature, so that you don't even have to worry about closing anything (manually) in the first place.

```
try (Connection cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(database.getDB_URL());
     PreparedStatement p = cnn.prepareStatement(query)) {
  // prepare your statement
  try (ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery()) {
    // process result set
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected SQLException", e);
}
```